# Find Windows Update Given GUID from windowsupdate.log?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-patching

When I look through the C:\windows\windowsupdate.log I see events like this :

```
Added update {19a3a735-8458-4b6c-baa8-eef88e4058cf}.201 to search result
```

How can I map a guid given in this way to an update? What is the significance of the .201? (or 200 or whatever, it varies)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs says that for a given update revision (modified and republished on a service like Windows Update or WSUS), it keeps the same update ID (GUID) and get an incremented Revision number, which are often shown together  as "{GUID}.revision.", but it also gets a unique Revision ID for that particular service. WindowsUpdate.log identifies them with the former identifier syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If your update is finally selected for installation, you will find additional entries in the windowsupdate.log

```
Updates to download = 1
   Title = Some text description of the update
   UpdateId = {19a3a735-8458-4b6c-baa8-eef88e4058cf}.201
```

Otherwise, for a local WSUS server maybe an approach such as [How to get a list of every WSUS update using PowerShell](https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/how-to-get-a-list-of-every-wsus-update-using-powershell/) might be useful. For MS updates, the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) shuld be queryable by id (I cannot test that from my OS).